# STS Crash after project spring version upgrade 3 -> 4

Tags: spring, eclipse, crash, spring-tool-suite

Our application was using spring version 3.2.3.RELEASE and we decided to migrate it to 4.0.9.RELEASE.

After the upgrade we were unable to ever use STS again. When launch the workspace, STS stops responding after some time (5-30 min).

We tried downloading a STS new version, creating new workspaces, disabling all validations. Nothing worked so far but if we use a regular eclipse version we have no problems at all.

Does anyone have an idea on what could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to open an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and provide more details.

Especially interesting will be to capture a thread dump while STS is being unresponsive (using jps and jstack). Would be great if you could attach a few of them to the issue.

You also said that you ran a fresh STS installation (I assume STS 3.9.x) with a fresh workspace. So what exactly did you do before STS becomes unresponsive?

Comment: The crashes appears to be random. We can't really identify an obvious cause. This is happening to 5 different developers. For example if i open my workspace and edit a file STS just crashes after the save.

Comment: This seems to be the related issue at GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/218